# How to install broadcom 4313 driver?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I try all methods in the ask ubuntu but it didn't work.

`lspci -nn | grep Wireless` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

`lshw -C network` output:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
       açıklama: Network controller
       ürün: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       üretici: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       sürüm: 01
       genişlik: 64 bits
       saat: 33MHz
       kapasiteler: bus_master cap_list
       yapılandırma: latency=0
       kaynaklar: bellek:c2500000-c2503fff
  *-network
       açıklama: Eternet interface
       ürün: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       üretici: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       mantıksal ad: eth0
       sürüm: 05
       serial: 2c:27:d7:d9:94:7b
       boyut: 100Mbit/s
       kapasite: 100Mbit/s
       genişlik: 64 bits
       saat: 33MHz
       kapasiteler: bus_master cap_list eternet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       yapılandırma: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.63 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       kaynaklar: irq:41 ioport:3000(boyut=256) bellek:c0404000-c0404fff bellek:c0400000-c0403fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modprobe to install the "wl" driver.

```
sudo modprobe wl
```